# python selenium click on button xpath error

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape an airbnb listing. I cant figure out a way to get the full list of amenities other than clicking on "more". I am using selenium to simulate the click, but it does nt seem to work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/4660676'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="expandable-trigger-more"]')
actions.click(elem).perform()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?  What happens?  Nothing?  Do you get an error?

Comment: you haven't define your `actions` instance of `ActionChains` so line `actions.click(elem).perform()` have no sense

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The XPath itself is correct, but you have not defined the `actions`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="expandable-trigger-more"]')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(elem).perform()
```

Note that you can simply use the `WebElement`'s `click()` method instead:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="expandable-trigger-more"]')
elem.click()
```

Works for me.

---

If you are getting `NoSuchElementException` error, you might need to wait for the link to be clickable via [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) and `element_to_be_clickable`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="expandable-trigger-more"]'))
)
element.click()
```

Comment: @Borat14 works for me, you are doing smth more than just clicking more button probably. Post the complete code you have so far. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, on the first methods i get this error:

    WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (661.5, 10.316665649414062). Other element would receive the click: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="sticky-md-book-it-btn"></button>

on the last two methods i get 

 "string indices must be integers"

Comment: This is the code  

`from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains  

url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/4660676'  

driver = webdriver.Firefox()  
driver.get(url)  

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="expandable-trigger-more"]')  

actions = ActionChains(driver)  
actions.click(elem).perform()`

Comment: @Borat14 the "string indexes must be integers" is because of the selenium 2.49 bug, downgrade to 2.48: `pip install selenium==2.48` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969006/python-selenium-click-and-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers).

Answer (score 1):

**A very simple way of achieving this is given below**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="expandable-trigger-more"]').click()
```

It works for me hope will work for you as well.