# Selecting options from Auto Complete Dropdown using selenium web driver in python

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I have to select options from a drop down on a page. I tried the below code but it is showing a syntax error. Can somebody help me with this?

```
web_element x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtSearchPhone"]')
Select sel = new Select(x)
sel.select_by_value("Iphone")
```

I tries Web_element, WebElement too. 
But this is showing syntax error for the very first line.

```
web_element x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtSearchPhone"]')
            ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using selenium (python) to select an option from a conditional dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068238/using-selenium-python-to-select-an-option-from-a-conditional-dropdown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code block to select the option `Apple iPhone 6 128GB` from the suggestions:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r"C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://tradein.vodafone.co.uk/#/topmodel')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtSearchPhone']").send_keys("Apple iPhone 6 128GB")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='ui-menu-item']/a[contains(@id, 'ui-id-')][text()='Apple iPhone 6 128GB']")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']/a[contains(@id, 'ui-id-')][text()='Apple iPhone 6 128GB']").click()
```

Comment: I am still getting an error, 'Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <input>'

Comment: The error says it all. The element returned by `driver.find_element_by_id("txtSearchPhone")` is an `input` tag **not a select tag**. How can you apply `Select sel = new Select(x)` on it?

Comment: can you share the relevant `HTML` or the `url` if it is a public one?

Comment: https://tradein.vodafone.co.uk/#/topmodel . I am entering Apple iPhone 6 128GB in the search box and it appears as a dropdown. I want to select that.

Comment: Thanx a lot!!:)

Answer (score 1):

what you're typing is not valid Python.  Are you looking at an actual Python example?

```
## not valid Python code.
web_element x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtSearchPhone"]')
Select sel = new Select(x)
sel.select_by_value("Iphone")
```

what you need to do is find the select box...

```
select_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yourSelectBoxId"]')
```

than iterate your select box...

```
for i in select_box:
    if i.text == "some text":
        i.click();
```

Before all of that, you probably need to spend some time learning the Python language.

Comment: Yeah, i got that.   Can i directly have Iphone as an option, instead of creating a loop?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.   Some dropdowns these days are loaded when they are clicked, it really depends on the site.  Most of the time, I need to iterate the select box values to select the right text or value which matches what I'm looking for.

Comment: Its showing an error of 'Webelement is not iterable'

Comment: that's because you must have selected an element that was not a select box.

Comment: yes, it was a search box rather than a drop down box

Comment: I got another answer..so, not this time!

Answer (score 1):

Python is a Dynamically typed language, you don't need to specify the type of the variable when you declare a variable.

`a=10`
creates a int and

`name="hello world"` creates a string

Comment: Thanx, got that!. But that hasn't solved my problem.